# Why are questions with no recent activity, and not bumped by Community, on the front page?

Tags: support, recent-activity

Tonight I saw this on the front page:

[image: screen shot]

These aren't Community bumps that are somehow being misreported; both questions have upvoted answers and shouldn't have been eligible for a bump.  Nor have there been recent deleted answers there (that somehow aren't being reported).  I see nothing special in the timeline for either question.

I don't *mind*, and I don't have anything against these two questions.  I'm just puzzled.

Comment: I see the question above those two (Mount Everest) and the question below those two (burning Earth) one above the other, but I don't see a spot where those two questions should be - in between them; they're not anywhere else on the list. Perhaps it's like #12, Grimmauld Place, in Harry Potter: I, a muggle (non-mod) can't see them, whereas you, a wizard, can see that that space exists. I was going to guess that you were on the "hot" tab, but it's not showing up there. Or the "week" or "month" tabs. Or on "frequent".

Comment: Alternatively, an edit could have been removed during the grace period. That would still show up on the history of the answers, though, and it doesn't in the more recent one (Two ships).

Comment: @HDE226868 I was on the "active" tab, i.e. the default if you go to the site.  I don't see them now either; curiouser and curiouser.

Comment: I've clicked on just about every button on the homepage, and I can't reproduce it. Hm. Do you have any tags blocked, or any favorite tags? That would bump other questions away.

Comment: I can't reproduce it now either.  No blocked or favorite tags, no relevant browser add-ons/scripts.  It's weird.  Glad I took the screenshot!

Comment: This is getting weird. (*shouting*) Has anyone else been able to replicate or falsify this?

Comment: I don't remember which question it was for, but I deleted one of my old questions a couple days ago and it completely disappeared.  I couldn't find a record of it anywhere.  I have others I deleted and they show up just fine.

Comment: [It's on Meta!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252534/something-is-wrong-with-posts-being-bumped-i-think)

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to make a community wiki post of all the things that *haven't* caused this, because, quite frankly, I'd still like to solve this . . . somehow.

**Things that didn't cause this weird bug:**

- Being on a different tab (e.g. active, hot, week, month, frequent)
- Having specific tags blocked/favorited
- Having an edit on the posts being removed during a grace period
- Having an edit on the posts rolled back
- Monica being a moderator
- The questions being unanswered and being bumped by the Community user
- Monica being adept at Photoshop
- . . .

Anything else would help solve this.

Comment: As some evidence of my lack of aptitude with Photoshop et al I offer [this attempt at a community-promotion ad](http://meta.communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/a/1227/83).  You might say that "yeah, she's just saying that/faking it", but I want Community Building to succeed more than I want to pull shenanigans on anybody!  Especially unexciting shenanigans like this; surely I'd save it for something better, right?  You have only my word on all that, I know.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Don't worry; I trust you! Have you guys used that ad yet?

Comment: We're currently waiting for somebody with actual graphics skills to finish cleaning it up.  The troll looks much better now; now we're just waiting for crosshairs, the text, and sizing.  Plus actually submitting it, of course.

Comment: We've been trying to make an ad for HSM, but none of us are too skilled in art to make on. Our default "days in beta" ad has gotten loads of upvotes on Math . . . with the caveat that we replace it. Anyway, I hope we resolve this soon.